# LNK 2019 error on Windows forms (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, forms

I have C++ code which calls routines from Mathworks. The code works properly in a console application. However I get linker error 2019 pointing to the Mathworks routines when I create a Windows forms app with the same code. I compare the linker properties sheets between the working and error producing projects (MS VS2010) - all paths and library targets are the same. Do I need some special treatment for external routines in a Windows forms app? THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP.

Here is text from one of 8 linker errors:

> Error 26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" char *
>   * __clrcall matGetDir(class MATFile *,int *)" (?matGetDir@@$$J0YMPEAPEADPEAVMATFile@@PEAH@Z) referenced in function
>   "int __clrcall AnalyzeMatFile(wchar_t const *,class
>   std::basic_ofstream > *,class
>   std::basic_ofstream > *,class
>   std::vector,class std::allocator >,class
>   std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > &)"
>   (?AnalyzeMatFile@@$$FYMHPEB_WPEAV?$basic_ofstream@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@1AEAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@2@@Z) C:\Users\TAS_PB_Usr1\00_TAS\500_Prod_Dev\160302_MatAloguer\ReadWorkspaceVars\ReadWorkspaceVars\Functions.obj    ReadWorkspaceVars

Thank you both for answers.
Yes there is reference to the Matlab libraries.

I tried the #pragma directives (now commented) per recommendation:

```
//#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "engine.h"
#include "mat.h"
//#pragma managed(pop)
```

And indeed specifying un-managed changed the link error message from "__clrcall" to "__cdecl" (same number of errors). However I found by "luck" that changing the platform from 32 bit to 64 bit (this PC is 64 bit) eliminated the errors. I don't understand that (in particular why console app works and forms app does not) - and would like to - but I'm happy that the code builds now. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Did you actually add  a reference to the Mathworks library to your project?

Comment: These are native C functions but you didn't tell the compiler about it.  Which is how it ended up with `__clrcall` instead of `__cdecl`.  Put #pragma managed(push, off) before the #include directive, #pragma managed(pop) after it.  Your AnalyzeMatFile() function doesn't look very healthy either, only compile with /clr in effect for code that *should* be compiled as managed code.